# Streamwriter is only printing the first line of loop to CSV file

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I made a quick program so I could get data from the collatz conjecture to graph and I am trying to write it to a csv with the result amount in column 1 and the number of the number of the step in column 2. but for some reason the streamwriter is only outputting the first line in each row. how do I get the streamwriter to update before writing to the CSV file?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)

    {

        int y;


        BigInteger x;

        System.Collections.ArrayList ResultsArray = new System.Collections.ArrayList();

        System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\public\testfolder\writelines2.csv");


        x = BigInteger.Pow(15, 15);
        y = 1;

        var ColumnWriter = string.Format("{0},{1}",x, y);
        do
        {

            if (x % 2 != 0)

            {
                x = (x * 3) + 1;
                Console.WriteLine(x);
                ResultsArray.Add(x);
            }
            else
            {

                x = (x / 2);
                Console.WriteLine(x);
                ResultsArray.Add(x);
            }

           file.WriteLine(ColumnWriter);
            y = y + 1;


        } while (x > 1);

        file.Flush();
        Console.ReadLine();
}
}
```

}

Comment: "the first line in each row". What does that even mean?

Comment: It is reprinting the first itteration of the loop in each row instead of the next one so it looks like this"437893890380859375,1
437893890380859375,1
437893890380859375,1
437893890380859375,1
437893890380859375,1
437893890380859375,1
437893890380859375,1
437893890380859375,1
437893890380859375,1
437893890380859375,1
437893890380859375,1
437893890380859375,1
437893890380859375,1
437893890380859375,1
437893890380859375,1
437893890380859375,1
437893890380859375,1
437893890380859375,1

Answer (score 1):

You don't update the string variable ColumnWriter inside the loop. Put

```
ColumnWriter = string.Format("{0},{1}",x, y);
```

before or after (depending on what/when you want to output) the line

```
file.WriteLine(ColumnWriter);
```